# How to repeat Input layer until it exceeds a certain amount of neurons?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

the shape of my Input layer is (None,), and I want to repeat the Input until it exceeds a certain amount. (for example until exceeds (7,))

here is my code:

```
import keras

least_accepted = 7 #the least accepted length
Inpt_lyr = keras.Input(shape = (None,))
nxt_lyr = keras.layers.RepeatVector(least_accepted)(Inpt_lyr)
nxt_lyr = keras.layers.Reshape((-1,))
# and so on...
```

but i'm not sure if it is the optimized way. for example, if the minimum  accepted length  is 7, i want for inputs with length 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, results be like these:
1 -> 7, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 9, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 12. that is their first multiples which is greater than 7.
any help is really appreciated...

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your lengths, can you explain it better?

Comment: sure. imagine the least accepted length is 7. then i want a sequence with length less than 7, get repeated until the final length become greater than 7.

Comment: for example if length is one, it should be repeated until become with length 7. (repeated 7 times). for length 2, it should repeated 4 times to get the length 8 (first multiple of 2 which is greater than 7).

Comment: generally for lengths 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 (which are less than 7), should be mapped to their first multiple which is greater or equal to 7, that are 7, 8, 9, 8, 10, 12 respectively

Comment: 7=(1 * 7), 8=(2 * 4), 9=( 3 * 3), 8=(4 * 2), 10=(5 * 2), 12=(6 * 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function:

```py
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from keras.backend import tf
import numpy as np

minLength = 7

def expandData(x):
    one = K.ones((1,), dtype='int32')
    repetitions = K.cast(tf.ceil(minLength / K.shape(x)[-1:]), 'int32')
    repetitions = K.concatenate([one, repetitions])
    return K.tile(x, repetitions)
```

A working test:

```py
inputs = Input((None,))
outputs = Lambda(expandData)(inputs)
model = Model(inputs, outputs)

inputData = [np.arange(i+1).reshape((1,-1)) for i in range(10)]
for inputs in inputData:
    preds = model.predict(inputs)

    print('\ninput sequence - len=', len(inputs[0]), ' - ', inputs)
    print('output sequence - len=', len(preds[0]), ' - ',  preds)
```